# How can I open Google maps in walking mode

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, android-activity

How can I start Google Maps at walking mode to a destination? I know how to open in navigation mode. I have not found a way to open it in plain walking mode

Comment: You put your mark when your need to go. At the right size click on the car button and a new activity will open showing the differente way, it is here where you can change to select a walking mode.

Comment: @JavaJade:I don't understand what you mean. My question is how can I start google maps from my activity and show the walking direction of the destination I provide

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the `mode` parameter as part of your Directions request. `mode` is one of the optional request parameters that specifies the mode of transport to use when calculating directions. If no mode is specified, the Google Maps Embed API will show one or more of the most relevant modes for the specified route.

Below is a sample Direction request that returns walking directions from Indianapolis to Chicago. If the parameter `&mode=walking` was removed, the request will return the directions with most relevant modes instead.

```
https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/directions?key=[YOUR API KEY]&origin=indianapolis&destination=chicago&avoid=tolls|highways&mode=walking
```

Reference: 
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide

Comment: I am talking about opening the app not the browser. Does not do that for the app

Comment: Are you trying to use the native Maps implementation or are you trying to create your own?

Comment: I am trying to open the google maps app installed on the phone passing the relevent intent

Comment: If you are talking about the Google Maps application, I guess you cannot set it to walking as default mode when you launch the application. However, it seems that Maps app can remember your last navigation mode. If you selected walking mode from your last navigation, then it will be the mode on your next navigation.

Comment: If you are talking about doing it to a map application, below is a sample implementation. The Intent will request walking direction to Eiffel Tower in Paris

`Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q=Eiffel+Tower,+Paris+France&mode=w");
Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
startActivity(mapIntent);`

Additional information and guide:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/intents

Comment: Yes that opens the google maps in navigation mode. My question is how to open google maps and only display the route

Comment: I believe this cannot be done using the built-in Google Map. What I can suggest is for you to do it programmatically utilizing the Maps APIs.

Answer (score 0):

It is really just a case of pushing directions instead of start right after you set the address. Directions gives you a chance to change the vehicle. If you go directly to start you won’t see that option.